# WSO2 - Problem when trying to save a Proxy Service or Sequence

Tags: java, wso2, esb, wso2-enterprise-integrator

i have an detault installation of WSO2 EI 6.5.0 and when I am trying to save an existing proxy service i recive a "Read Only" ERROR on log.

> [2019-06-25 08:06:44,865] [-1234] [] [http-nio-9443-exec-40]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.mediation.dependency.mgt.DependencyTracker} -  Proxy service : FileProxy_Tienda_Stock was removed from the Synapse configuration successfully
>   [2019-06-25 08:06:44,867] [-1234] [] [http-nio-9443-exec-40]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.mediation.dependency.mgt.DependencyTracker} -  Proxy service : FileProxy_Tienda_Stock was added to the Synapse configuration successfully
>   [2019-06-25 08:06:44,867] [-1234] [] [http-nio-9443-exec-40]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.ProxyService} -  Building Axis service for Proxy service : FileProxy_Tienda_Stock
>   [2019-06-25 08:06:44,868] [-1234] [] [http-nio-9443-exec-40]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.ProxyService} -  Adding service FileProxy_Tienda_Stock to the Axis2 configuration
>   [2019-06-25 08:06:44,869] [-1234] [] [http-nio-9443-exec-40]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.DeploymentInterceptor} -  Deploying Axis2 service: FileProxy_Tienda_Stock {super-tenant}
>   [2019-06-25 08:06:44,870] [-1234] [] [http-nio-9443-exec-40]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.ProxyService} -  Successfully created the Axis2 service for Proxy service : FileProxy_Tienda_Stock
>   [2019-06-25 08:06:47,322] [-1] [] [Thread-21] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.mediation.initializer.persistence.ProxyServiceStore} -  Error while saving the proxy service: FileProxy_Tienda_Stock to the file system
>   java.io.IOException: Destination '././repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/proxy-services/FileProxy_Tiendas_Stock.xml' exists but is read-only
>           at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyFile(FileUtils.java:1089)
>           at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyFile(FileUtils.java:1038)
>           at org.apache.synapse.config.xml.MultiXMLConfigurationSerializer.writeToFile(MultiXMLConfigurationSerializer.java:758)
>           at org.apache.synapse.config.xml.MultiXMLConfigurationSerializer.serializeProxy(MultiXMLConfigurationSerializer.java:412)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.mediation.initializer.persistence.ProxyServiceStore.saveToFile(ProxyServiceStore.java:47)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.mediation.initializer.persistence.ProxyServiceStore.saveToFile(ProxyServiceStore.java:32)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.mediation.initializer.persistence.AbstractStore.save(AbstractStore.java:78)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.mediation.initializer.persistence.MediationPersistenceManager.persistElement(MediationPersistenceManager.java:476)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.mediation.initializer.persistence.MediationPersistenceManager.access$1400(MediationPersistenceManager.java:71)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.mediation.initializer.persistence.MediationPersistenceManager$MediationPersistenceWorker.run(MediationPersistenceManager.java:452)
>   [2019-06-25 08:06:47,326] [-1] [] [Thread-21] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.mediation.initializer.persistence.MediationPersistenceManager} -  Error while saving mediation configuration changes
>   org.wso2.carbon.mediation.initializer.persistence.ServiceBusPersistenceException: Error while saving the proxy service: FileProxy_Tienda_Stock to the file system
>           at org.wso2.carbon.mediation.initializer.persistence.AbstractStore.handleException(AbstractStore.java:206)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.mediation.initializer.persistence.ProxyServiceStore.saveToFile(ProxyServiceStore.java:49)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.mediation.initializer.persistence.ProxyServiceStore.saveToFile(ProxyServiceStore.java:32)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.mediation.initializer.persistence.AbstractStore.save(AbstractStore.java:78)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.mediation.initializer.persistence.MediationPersistenceManager.persistElement(MediationPersistenceManager.java:476)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.mediation.initializer.persistence.MediationPersistenceManager.access$1400(MediationPersistenceManager.java:71)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.mediation.initializer.persistence.MediationPersistenceManager$MediationPersistenceWorker.run(MediationPersistenceManager.java:452)
>   Caused by: java.io.IOException: Destination '././repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/proxy-services/FileProxy_Tiendas_Stock.xml' exists but is read-only
>           at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyFile(FileUtils.java:1089)
>           at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyFile(FileUtils.java:1038)
>           at org.apache.synapse.config.xml.MultiXMLConfigurationSerializer.writeToFile(MultiXMLConfigurationSerializer.java:758)
>           at org.apache.synapse.config.xml.MultiXMLConfigurationSerializer.serializeProxy(MultiXMLConfigurationSerializer.java:412)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.mediation.initializer.persistence.ProxyServiceStore.saveToFile(ProxyServiceStore.java:47)
>           ... 5 more

[File_Proxy](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JR7Y4Q1E1svvh0rc6FIsU-CRxja0GTYq/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Can you share the proxy, seems like there is issue with the proxy service

Comment: Ok @amg_amit. But i´ve the same problem with sequences.I wil add the proxy to the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like a permission issue. Can you check on the server user for running wso2 service has read/write permissions for artifact location? You can get the server user for wso2 server by command: **ps -ef|grep wso2**. Then you can check the permission for the artifact location by executing the following command.

```
ls -lrt repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/
```

If the server user doesn't have write permission for the artifact location you need to provide the ownership to the user for the artifact location[1]

[1] -https://askubuntu.com/questions/6723/change-folder-permissions-and-ownership

Comment: thank you @quark i can solve the issiue with your answer